# How to override only few methods of interface?

Tags: java, interface

Let's suppose i have an interface which have few methods like following:

```
public interface Person {

    public void printName(String name);

    public int getAge(String name);

    public String getAddress();

}
```

Now a Test class implementing the above interface like following:

```
public class Test implements Person{

}
```

Now eclipse showing me an error and forcing me to add unimplemented methods.

Now i want to implement only  `printName()` method of `Person` interface in `Test` class. How can i do it. I mean to ask how to implement only required method not all ?

**Note** i do not want to use Abstract class.

Comment: Default implementation is your only hope.

Comment: If you don't want all the methods, don't implement the interface https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80746

Comment: @aka-one default implementation is included in java 8 i am currently using java 7.

Comment: Your only choice in Java 7 is to have an abstract class or implement all methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `Test` class implements `Person` interface, this means it must implement all methods of that interface.

The exceptions:

1. If `Test` is an abstract class, it doesn't have to implement all the methods of `Person`, but any concrete sub-class of `Test` will have to implement the remaining methods.
2. Any methods for which the `Person` interface contains a default implementation don't have to be implemented by `Test`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 or higher you can use **default** key word for the methods that you don't want to implement in Implementation class

```
public interface Person {

  public void printName(String name);

  public default int getAge(String name){
    return -1;
  }

  public default String getAddress(){
    return null;
   }
```

Comment: This won't compile as you need to provide an implementation for a default method.

Comment: @NicholasK Yes. You are correct. I updated the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: This still isn't a good solution, as the whole point of this interface is almost defeated IMO. And also as per OP's comment he's on Java 7 so this definitely won't work.

Comment: This might worked on java 8 but definitely not work for me.

Comment: Works perfectly . (using java 8)

Comment: @NicholasK Agree that this does not help for java version below 8. Mentioned that in my answer " If you are using Java 8...."  .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using interface, you have to implement all the methods from the interface. Better you use abstract methods.

Example:

```
abstract class Person {
    abstract void printName(String name);
    abstract int getAge(String name);
    abstract String getAddress();
}
```

Comment: Question clearly says *without using abstract class*